# React useState: object as state, how to update a string value by replacing and avoid cancat?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

simple question but I am really surprised that:

1. the `useState` hook would handle strings in object in such a way
2. I'm having difficulty finding questions from other developers on this issue.

```
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    offDays: [0, 6],  // by javascript convention, Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on. 
    officeHourStart: "",
    officeHourEnd: "",
    billingClosingDay: 25,
    displayLanguage: "en",
  }); 

  return (
      ... other code ...
                <ToggleButtonGroup
                  value={formState.displayLanguage}
                  onChange={(event, selectedLanguage) => {setFormState({...formState, displayLanguage: selectedLanguage})}}
                  aria-label="select Display Language"
                >
                  <ToggleButton value="ja" aria-label="bold" className={classes.toggleButton}> 
                    <p>Japanese</p>
                  </ToggleButton>        

                  <ToggleButton value="cn" aria-label="bold" className={classes.toggleButton}>
                    <p>Chinese</p>
                  </ToggleButton>

                  <ToggleButton value="en" aria-label="bold" className={classes.toggleButton}>
                    <p>English</p>
                  </ToggleButton>
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
     ... code ... 


  )
```

When I select "Japanese" as `displayLanguage` by clicking the toggle button, and console logging the updated `formState` value, this is what shows up:

```
formState:  
{
offDays: Array(2), 
officeHourStart: Sun Dec 31 1899 09:30:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), 
officeHourEnd: Sun Dec 31 1899 18:30:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), 
billingClosingDay: 25, 
displayLanguage: 'enjp',  // why concat?????? 
…
```

Why is it concatenating the string????
How do I replace the value of `displayLanguage` from `en` to `ja`????
Why is useState handling string updates this way? It does not make any sense .....

Comment: Could you do a `console.log(selectedLanguage)` inside the `onChange` handler to make sure it's not a problem with the `ToggleButtonGroup`/`ToggleButton` components?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please update state like following.

```
setFormState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    displayLanguage: selectedLanguage
 }));
```

Comment: my bad.  I should specify `exclusive` on `ToggleButtonGroup`. It is now accepting multi-select. That's why it is concating